# Is it possible to configure JBoss/Wildfly datasources to use changing client credentials?

Tags: dynamic, jboss, credentials, wildfly

I know it is not the usual way. We are using an existing Oracle DB with many stored procedures. The Procedures are using variables USER in many ways. Also the licensing does not allow to use "functional" User logins, each user must use his own account.

The the question came up: Is it possible to configure the JBoss/Wildfly Database Connection pool to hold / create connections with different credentials, that are given at logon time?

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be creating a Datasource dynamically using the CLI's Model API. See the following example:

```
public void createDatasource() throws Exception{
  ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
  request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(ClientConstants.ADD);
  request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem",
          "datasources");
  request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("data-source",
          "java:jboss/datasources/NewDatasource");
  request.get("jndi-name").set("java:jboss/datasources/NewDatasource");
  request.get("connection-url").set("jdbc:as400://1.2.3.4/SCHEME");
  request.get("driver-class").set("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
  request.get("driver-name").set("jt400.jar");
  request.get("user-name").set("username");
  request.get("password").set("password");
  request.get("pool-name").set("pool_NewDatasource");
  ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(
          InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9999);
  client.execute(new OperationBuilder(request).build());
}
```

Hope it helps